# ALDB authentication request

Tags: clearcase, clearquest

So I have a setup where clearcase and clearquest are integrated.

I.E. if I check in a file in clearcase clearquest will popup asking for a change request number.

Here's the deal, I don't have to "login" every time I start a new clearexplorer.

I have some other tools I have been writing that I would like to take advantage of that capability but I don't know where to start. Basically I want my tool to check the same place clearcase checks to see that I'm a valid user and create my object based on those credentials.

From the looks of things the ALDB server might have something to do with it but I don't know how to interact with it.

Anyone have any ideas on it?

UPDATE:
I guess What I mean is I don't have to login to Clearquest every time I open a new clearcase and check in files. That's what I'm really looking for. using the existing clearquest "authentication" object (If that's what its even called)

Update 2:
Based on Information I found here:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.apiref.doc/c_perf_user_admin.htm

You can use this method to obtain the Session object associated with the current user. See the description of the Session object for more information on how to use this object.

I look at Session Object and it doesn't seem to mention about how to use this object as it states.

Update #3

This has been a long time, but it's come up again, I think what I'm really looking to do is build something that shares the Session object since logging in takes quite a while my plan is to login once using a background process, and then I can query that running process for the object when I try to login with a second program, if it works all goes well and continues, if it doesn't then it will require a manual login, (or could spawn the process that logs in, and waits for a response).

If/When I make this I'll post some details on steps I took.

Answer (score 2):

It is true the albd service (Atria Location Broker Daemon) requires a Windows account to function. But not yours. See [Updating the Windows ClearCase ALBD Password](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/07/0703_nellis/index.html).

> The last one, the `ALBD` service, requires a Windows user account with ClearCase privileges to function properly.
>   In the definition of this service, during ClearCase installation, the ClearCase administrator must specify the name of this privileged account, the password, the Windows domain, and the Windows group for this account.

Any ClearCase-related operation will based the user identification on the

- [`credmap`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/credmap.htm) informations (if you are with Windows clients and Unix server)

  credmap registryServer
- or the `creds.exe` informations

The clearcase objects (like a new version created after a checkin) will get those credentials.

Comment: So to associate a file in clearquest with that is really the key part as I don't have to "login" to clearcase at any rate (other then logging into my machine...) I've updated my question.

Comment: @onaclov2000 Regarding ClearQuest, do you have it linked with LDAP? (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.admin.doc/ldap/c_ldap_auth_model.htm)

Comment: We have user/passwords that are different then login info. Ldap actually sounds like it would be a logical choice but I am unable to change that (I'm not an admin in any way), There is a "rare" occasion where we have to login, but that usually occurs if we are tryin to check a file in and haven't logged into clearquest since rebooting the machine, which leads me to believe that there is a "floating object" out there I can access..(hopefully)